# Getting page to delay reload using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to program a 3 second delay when the form is submitted. Right now, on submit the standard text fades out, and the notification text fades in, but the page reloads before you have a chance to read it.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function changeText() { 
$('#free-planner').fadeOut('slow', function() {
       document.getElementById('free-planner').innerHTML = 'Check your email!';   }); {  $('#free-planner').fadeIn('slow', function() {  });    
 }   
} 
</script>
```

Comment: seems like you should be fading in the message once the page reloads.... not the other way around.

Comment: You could wrap your submit code in a setTimeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, prevent the submit event, then fire it programatically when you are ready..

```
$('form').on('submit', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  form = $(this);
  fp = $('#free-planner');
  fp.fadeOut('slow', function () {
    fp.text('Check your email!').fadeIn('slow', function() {
      form.submit();
    });
  });
});
```

All this stuff should probably happen after the form is submit.  Maybe you want a hidden iframe which is the target of your form?  Then you can submit the form without updating the current page in the browser.  Something like:

```
form = $('form');
$('body').append($('<iframe>').attr({ name:"hiddenifr", id:"hiddenifr" }).css({ display: 'none' }));

form.attr('target', 'hiddenifr');
form.on('submit', function(ev) {
  fp = $('#free-planner')
  fp.fadeOut('slow', function() {
    fp.text('Check your email!').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I have an idea of how this works, I don't understand how that fades in the new fp.text, as there is only a fp.fadeOut. for form= $(@); should @ be replaced with the form class as in: form = $(.submit-form) ?

Comment: Or submit the form/json via ajax, and use jquery events, more advanced but not needed depending on your situation.  Additionally, you could just have the submit decoupled from the fadeout, ie separation of concerns, using events as well.  Might help for browser compatibility etc, as the form should submit even if your gui stuff fails.

Comment: Made a few other corrections - fades should be right now in both samples.